# How to fire "scrollsToTop" after tapping the status bar programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, tableview

I want to fire scrollsToTop function which fired when you tap the status bar programmatically if users tap the navigation bar title.

This is my method at the moment.

```
[tableView_ setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
[tableView_ flashScrollIndicators];
```

But, it does not animate ScrollIndicators like you tap the status bar to scroll to the top.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
-(void)doScroll{
    void (^scroll)(void) = ^{
        [contentTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
        [contentTableView flashScrollIndicators];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:scroll];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doScroll) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Friedgaad, but the table view cells disappear while scrolling in this method *_*.

Comment: I just tested this on a tableview and the cells dissapper if my view is being animated (in my case an flip). So I added a performSelector:@selector afterDelay: and the cells are then shown.

Comment: thank you,  but I got [ReadItLaterViewController scroll]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8bee9a0 after loading my app.

It seems I need to declear "scroll", but I couldn't declear this    void (^scroll)(void) in @interface.  

Sorry for my limited knowleage for this, this function might be C? And, is there any reason for CGPointMake(0, 3000) instead of (0,0) ?

Comment: Also, if I scroll the current table view to the point where I can see the 9th table view cell, and fire doscroll method, the table view cells disappear.  But, if I just scroll the table view to the bottom a little, and fire doscroll method, it just scrolls to the top with indicator bar.

Comment: I just made a copy/paste error from my own code, it should be @selector(doscroll) and CGPointMake(0,0)!

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but still tabel view cells disappear.  Maybe, the table view cells are too many in my app.  Since, it works fine if I didn't scroll so much, just like 8 or 9 cells.  Thanks for your helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `-setContentOffset:animated` in combination with the UIScrollViewDelegate methods `- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` and/or `-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`?

You might be able to send your `-flashScrollIndicators` in one of those instead of relying on timers, i.e. by using `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ShouldStartLoadWithRequest Delegate method of web view

```
    ((UIScrollView *)[[self.challengeWebView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).scrollsToTop = NO;
```